# Lesson 3 for MSDN error SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: t-sql, msdn

i'm currently following this link and performing the steps

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170625.aspx

however, after importing in the Transact-SQL query, it tells me that

"Could not create a list of fields for the query. Verify that you connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct. Query (7,24) Parser: The syntax for 'sp' is incorrect"

What could be the problem? I have tested connection of the database and it is connected. (and yes, the table exists in the database)

Comment: What do you mean by importing the query, because I'd suggest there is some dodgy character in there. Paste the query into notepad or some such, make sure there's no rubbish in there, then paste it into the textbox.

Comment: I could not directly paste the sql query into the text box, so i placed that sql query into my notepad++ and saved it as .txt format (tried .sql format as well), then i import it. I didn't change anything.

Comment: Lets start back at the beginning have you confirmed that your query window is connected to the correct server and database?